# Bash java auto compiler

Tags: linux, bash, javac

I am currently trying to make a bash script that will go into every folder in ./ and compile blah.java, then run blah sending in a number for an input, and put the output in a file that I have named. I have something that is somewhat functional, but it only goes into the first directory, and after that it fails on me. I currently have...

```
#! /bin/bash


for i in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d)
do

    pwd
    cd $i
    pwd

    if [ -f "blah.java" ];
    then
        javac -cp . blah.java
        echo "17" | java -cp . blah - > blahresult17
        echo "43" | java -cp . blah - > blahresult43

    fi

done
```

I think it is having problems, because it is trying to go into a directory from ./ once it goes into a subdirectory, but obviously from the subdirectory it doesn't exist.

Comment: it seems like you could use _javac_ task of _ant_ rather than writing a script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a fi on your if, but that's presumably a cut and paste error, not the source of your failure.  The likely problem is that once you do the first cd, the following cd commands are relative to where you were, not where you are now.  You can work around this with pushd/popd instead, or running the cd and java bits in a subshell so that the cd does not persist to the next loop iteration.

Comment: Yes that was a cut/paste error. You were correct that it didn't go back up a directory

Answer (score 1):

You `cd` into the directory but never `cd` out of it.

My suggestion: use [`pushd`/`popd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushd_and_popd) instead of `cd`.

Replace `cd $i` with `pushd "$i"` and put `popd`at the end of your loop.

Also `for dir in */` would be a simpler solution to iterating all directories in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way, if you wanted to compile all the files with one invocation of javac, which allows javac to handle dependencies:

```
SRC=`find src -name "*.java"`
if [ ! -z $SRC ]; then
    javac -classpath $CLASSPATH -d obj $SRC
    # stop if compilation fails
    if [ $? != 0 ]; then exit; fi
fi
```